# Get data from the image asset

Tags: swift, uiimage, assets

I have an image in the assets catalog and I need to get this image (`UIImage`) with the scale parameter. There is only a `UIImage(data: scale:)` method, but I just can't get data from assets using the name. I always get `url = nil`. Maybe the problem is in the directory structure!?

**My code:**

```
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "countdown_photo_1", withExtension: "jpg") {
    return UIImage(data: try! Data(contentsOf: url), scale: scale)
}
```

**My directory structure:**

[image]

**My Contents.json:**

```
{
  "images" : [
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "countdown_photo_1.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "info" : {
    "version" : 1,
    "author" : "xcode"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try This code may be it's work for you

```
guard let img = UIImage(named: "countdown_photo_1.jpg") else { return }
let data = img.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Make a UITraitCollection by calling `init(displayScale:)` for the scale you want. Let's call that `tc`.
2. Now fetch the UIImage from the asset catalog by name in the usual way; let's call that `im`.
3. Extract its image asset (`im.imageAsset`); let's call that `asset`. This points us at the asset catalog's entry for the image *as a whole*.
4. Finally, ask the image asset for the image corresponding to the trait collection you created in the first step: `asset.image(with:tc)`.

That is the UIImage for the desired scale, and now if you need its data you can get it directly.

Answer (score 1):

To get an image from an asset library use:

```
UIImage(named: "countdown_photo_1")
```

The scale is automatically determined depending on the device. For `.jpg` files you should generally be including 1x, 2x, and 3x versions of the file in your asset library.

Due to iOS App Thinning, resolutions incompatible with the device are not included with the assets file. For example, 1x copies of the assets aren't included on 3x devices.

If you need the incompatible resolution files for some reason, then don't use asset libraries. Just include all the files directly in your bundle.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access the file directly, you can include it as a normal image outside of an asset catalog. Since Xcode 5 assets in .xcassets are in special file format which is impossible to access directly.